# How to calculate semi elasticity in fixed effect model with interaction

Tags: regression, r, fixed-effects

Given the model specification

$$Y_{it} = \beta_1 X_{it} + \beta_2 D*X_{it} + FE_{i} + e_{it}$$

The above model specification is a Fixed effect model with interaction term ($X_{it}$ interacting with D- i.e binary dummy variable[1,0])

Question

1.) If $Y_{it}$ is in log form and $X_{it}$ is (in percentages) unlogged, do I need to apply $100*(exp(\beta)-1)$ to both $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ to get the actual effect of $X_{it}$ on $Y_{it}$ when $D=1$?

2.) how do I interpret the effect?

Comment: If $Y_{it}$ is in log-form then why take the log of it on the linear regression equation?

Comment: Oh! The model specification has been edited. Hope it is clear. Thanks.